# Sifr3 displays black background after IE9 update

Tags: internet-explorer-9, sifr3

All my websites that use Sifr are displaying black background behind the replaced text.
Apparently since a recent update of IE9.
For example: http://simplex-interactive.nl/sifrtest/

Any solutions? I would be very grateful!
Basten